# Perform combinatorics with words that have repeated letters with Gtools package

Tags: r, combinations

Good morning, I need your help because I am solving the following problem:

**What is the number of words we can write with the letters of “ELECTROENCEFALOGRAMA”? There are 20 letters, of which L, C, O, A and R are repeated twice and E is repeated 4 times.**

I know that the problem is of combinatorics and I am approaching it in the following way using Rstudio and the gtools library

```
palabra_A <- c("E", "L", "E", "C", "T", "R", "O", "E", "N", "C", "E", "F", 
              "A", "L", "O", "G", "R", "A", "M", "A")

combinatoria_A <- combinations(20, 20, palabra_A, repeats.allowed = F)
```

The problem is that I get the following error which I have not been able to solve

```
> combinatoria_A <- combinations(20, 20, palabra_A, repeats.allowed = F)
Error in combinations(20, 20, palabra_A, repeats.allowed = F) : 
  too few different elements
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is a math problem and not a programing question. ie `factorial(length(palabra_A))/prod(factorial(table(palabra_A)))` is the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have a query, the variants of combinatorics do not come out due to the high number of them or because I consider numerical factors and not the letters as such? ... Anyway, thank you very much if it helped me

Comment: the matrix prouced is very very very very very very big.